# Can't make PostgreSQl instance

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

i am user postgresql 9.1

When i type the fallowing :

```
<?php
    new PostgreSQL ('localhost','5432','postgres','postgres','12345'); i get the error
?>
```

Fatal error: Class 'PostgreSQL' not found in /var/www/vhosts/task/db_actions.php on line 11

I tried with new Postgresql or new Pg_SQL but same thing. I am using Ubuntu, can anybody help

Answer (score 2):

Well, even if you had a PHP class called "PostgreSQL" (you don't - that's what the error is saying) you're just connecting then throwing the object away.

Perhaps take some time to read the PHP manuals, maybe search the internet and find a beginners guide or turorial you find helpful.

A description of the simple database access functions are [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php) and a popular cross-database wrapper is known as [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Good Luck!

---

Edited in response to comment:

If you know the correct driver class to use, and how to use it then why have you given a deliberately incorrect example of your code? If you know what the error means then you no longer have a question. You don't know what the error means because you asked. There is no (standard) class "PostgreSQL" that acts as a database driver that I know of. Nor are there "ASDFASDF" or "QWERTYUIOP" classes that will talk to a PostgreSQL database.

You're not using either of the two standard driver classes that I linked to. So, either you're advanced enough to have rejected those and written your own driver or you don't know what you're doing. If you've not found the standard drivers in the PHP manuals and/or don't know how to install them then you need to take the time to find a tutorial - you don't have one question, you've got dozens but can't see them yet because you're stuck behind this one.

Clearer now?

Comment: The moment when you start looking trough your own questions posted in stackoverflow throughout the years for the first time and find a question that does not even make any sense whatsoever. Not only that, but still, someone took the time to try and answer it :))) Kudos! Hope you are well, sir :)